# Компиляция программы с использованием PDCurses и Tiny C compiler (TCC) в Windows

Tags: c, windows, компиляция, библиотеки

Как в командной строке Windows правильно передать компилятору TCC параметры с указанием путей поиска файлов из библиотеки PDCurses?

Код hellocurses.c:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main(void){
    initscr();
    addstr("Hello PDCurses from tcc!\n");
    refresh();
    getch();

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Выполняю:

```
tcc hellocurses.c -o hellocurses
```

Сообщение компилятора:

```
hellocurses.c:1: error: include file 'curses.h' not found
```

Выполняю:

```
tcc hellocurses.c -IC:\PDCurses -o hellocurses
```

Сообщение компилятора:

```
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'initscr'
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'addstr'
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'refresh'
и т.д.
```

Выполняю:

```
tcc hellocurses.c -IC:\PDCurses -LC:\PDCurses\wincon -o hellocurses
```

Сообщение компилятора прежнее.

В папке C:\PDCurses находятся заголовочные файлы `curses.h, curspriv.h и panel.h`
В папке C:\PDCurses\wincon находится объектный код всех функций библиотеки и файл `pdcurses.lib`

Comment: `-lpdcurses` добавь… или просто `tcc hellocurses.c C:\PDCurses\wincon\pdcurses.lib -IC:\PDCurses`…

Comment: Сделал. Теперь компилятор пишет tcc: error: library 'pdcurses' not found

Comment: да забыл, что на win формат статических библиотек разный для разных компиляторов… на сколько я понимаю, `*.lib` — это статическая библиотека msvc, а gcc/tcc ищут статические библиотеки *.a… собственно вопрос: как именно ты собирал pdcurses/откуда её взял?

Comment: С помощью nmake из пакета Visual Studio

Comment: нум… вот и проблема: нужно собрать её с помощью `tcc`…

Comment: tcc вроде как не умеет полноценно делать PE бинари, только 32-битные. Порядок линковки библиотек описывается в доке tcc-win32.txt @Fat-Zer Не нужно.

Comment: @user7860670, ты уверен? в том же `tcc-win32.txt` написано: `On the object file level, currently TCC supports only the ELF format,  not COFF as used by MinGW and MSVC.  It is not possible to exchange object files or libraries between TCC and these compilers.` т.е чужую статику он прилинковать не сможет...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Там написано, как линковать динамические библиотеки. А *.lib - это не только статическая библиотека, но и еще библиотека импорта. И я даже думаю, что в этом случае это именно библиотека импорта, так как pdcurses вроде обычно в dll собиралась.

Comment: @user7860670, если верить [Makefile](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/blob/master/wincon/Makefile.vc)'у, то, если явно не указать `DLL=y`, по умолчанию собирается она как раз в статику… да и была б динамическая, то, подразумевая, что `*.dll` лежала рядом с `*.lib`, банальное `-lpdcurses` её бы нашло и просто прилинковало… да и OP про dll'ку ничего не сказал… + скорей всего, будут проблемы со следующим пунктом: `With DLLs, only functions (not data) can be im-/exported.`, а `curses` сильно полагается на глобальные переменные… Но я понимаю, что без подтверждения от OP'а это всё спекуляции…

Comment: Если я всё правильно понимаю, то библитека именно статическая, поскольку никаких dll рядом с ней не наблюдается и VS собирает проект в один исполняемый файл.

Comment: нум... тогда всё как я сказал выше: если нужно линковать эту библиотеку с помощью `tcc`, то её придётся собрать с помощью `tcc`…